# Sencha Architect removing my html on main page

Tags: html, overwrite, sencha-architect

Every time i save my project in Sencha Architect it overwrites any changes i do to the page that the ExtJS runs from (Let's call it App.html). Normally this doesn't effect much, (The Javascript is normally only looking at it's own objects and components) unless i want to include another stylesheet, another script or put an 'id' on any of the existing html tags.

Is there a way arround this? Can I tell it not to touch certain pages, or change it's memory of what is on them, or am i going to have to have a second HTML, one that includes all the same JS & ExtJS, but doesn't get editted because it isn't part of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the simple answer is *no you can't*.

You can however do as Dorvalla proposed and add new resources (just use the + button in the Project Inspector), and this works for additional JavaScripts and CSS-files. For instance this is a auto-generated app.html for a sencha touch project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Auto Generated with Sencha Architect -->
<!-- Modifications to this file will be overwritten. -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>llm</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css" id="appcss">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/llm.css" id="llm">
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="sdk/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
    <script src="functions.js" id="functions"></script>
    <script src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (!Ext.browser.is.WebKit) {
            alert("The current browser is unsupported.\n\nSupported browsers:\n" +
                "Google Chrome\n" +
                "Apple Safari\n" +
                "Mobile Safari (iOS)\n" +
                "Android Browser\n" +
                "BlackBerry Browser"
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

You can find more information about project resources at [docs.sencha.com](http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2/#!/guide/resources)

Comment: I almost forgot about this question... Yes, adding resources is the answer, and the Sencha Architect lets you add an Id onto the resources you add allowing me to do all 3 of the things i asked ( add a script, add a style sheet, put an id on either of those)

Answer (score 0):

for the stylesheet you can just add another resource, however for the additional javascript i just save the links and add them manually, which can be indeed a pain in the rear.

As adding multiple Id's, your bound with the same thing. I tried applying multiple Id's for components and it wouldn't accept it either, so in this case, i was fdorced to make every id different. For some odd reason it only wants to accept one class at my place as well, so somewhere it just doesn't make sense to me.